# Tensorflowjs expects 3 Dimensions, even though I trained it with 2 in Python

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am trying to test a model which I trained using XOR-Operator values in Python:

```
x_train = [[1,0],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]]
x_label = [1,1,0,0]

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, x_label, epochs=15)

prediction = model.predict([[5,5]])
print("Prediction: ", np.argmax(prediction[0]))
```

It works great in Python, but when I transform it into a Tensorflow JS file (model.json), it doesn't work anymore:

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "test_model")
```

As you can see above, I trained it with `input_shape=(2,1)`. But when I try it in Nodejs, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected flatten_input to have 3 dimension(s), but got array with shape [2,1]
```

My JS Code:

```
tf.loadLayersModel(model_url).then((model)=>{
        const input = tf.tensor([1,1],[2,1], "int32");
        const prediciton = model.predict(input)
        console.log(prediciton);
        response.send(prediciton);
        return null;
    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: The python code throws the same error as the js one. Your inputShape is [2, 1] which meant that  x_train should have the shape [b, 2, 1]

Comment: @edkeveked But it doesn't, it just works

Comment: Which version of tensorflow (python and js) are you using ?

Comment: Python: Google Colab Version; Nodejs: 2.4.0

Comment: Could I please share the colab with me here ?

Comment: @edkeveked Yes, Link; https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16aRs0Zmt71iTy0la8ivMCdHdj9Ig38pK?usp=sharing

Comment: I looked at your colab. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.tensor([1,1],[2,1])` (equivalent to the following array: `[[1], [1]]` will not work even in python). In python when the shape does not match, the dimension is expanded on the last axis. The resulting tensor will thus have the shape 2, 1, 1 which does not match the input shape that is expecting an input of shape `[b, 2, 1]`.

However `tf.tensor([1,1],[1,2])` will work in python because of the above. It seems however than in js broadcasting is only done when the input tensor is a tensor1d. So even this will not work.

To solve the issue in js, you can just consider expanding the tensor on the first axis (axis = 0) with the following:

```
tf.tensor([1,1],[1, 2,1], "int32")
```